# Grep/Gawk - If Line contains add to found.txt

Tags: awk, grep, gawk

Okay so basically I have one file containg emails & another 100 files containg ip      phone email

So what was wondering is if it was possible to check if line from folder containg the 100 .txt files contains email@email.com.

example of find.txt,

```
   123@hotmail.com
   123456@hotmail.com
   yahoo@yahoo.com
```

and so on..

example of 100txtfiles

```
   0.0.0.0       002921931      123@hotmail.com
   123.0.0.1 00029382    1235@hotmail.com
```

and so on..

So what I want is if 100txtfiles line contains email from find.txt then output to found.txt

Comment: What have you tried ? and what do you want to get in found .txt ? the whole line ?

Answer (score 0):

this line should work for you:

```
grep -Ff find.txt /dir/to/100.txt/*.txt > found.txt
```

If you just want the file name, add `-l` option:

```
grep -Flf find.txt .....
```

give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($3 in a)' find.txt path_to_100_files/*
   0.0.0.0       002921931      123@hotmail.com
```

Eventually you want to redirect the output to `found.txt` with `> found.txt` after the command above. Output is what it is as you didn't include an expected output in your question.